# Sanitise and validate $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] in recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha, sanitization

How do i sanitize and validate `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` in recaptcha

https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php#L72

Looks like it gives a long string of alphanumeric characters, `_` and `-`
so will using `strip_tags()` to sanitize and check if it has only alphanumeric characters, `_` and `-` to validate enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags` but this will not ensure that there are not other characters sent, like `@, #, ...`. One solution would be to use `preg_match` to validate the string you receive:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\w-]*$/', $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    echo 'invalid captcha';
}
```